# Make a user account on Windows 10 a full admin without lusrmgr.msc

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, administrator, privileges

I know how to create an admin-privileged user account on Windows 10
with `lusrmgr.msc`, but can't find how without. 
What other way(s) are there of doing this?

Comment: Try `net user /?` and go from there...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by avoiding the use of user manager?

Comment: @Ramhound I’m on home edition, I can’t use it.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7:

- You can do it with `Netplwiz.exe`.
- You can invoke `Netplwiz` with the command `control.exe userpasswords2`.
- You can do it with `compmgmt.msc`.
  This is a bit more tedious, as it’s a two-step operation:

  1. Create the user, and
  2. open its “Properties”, go to the “Member Of” tab,
     and add it to the “Administrators” group.

  I’m not sure whether this produces results
  identical to those produced by `Netplwiz`.

Comment: Thank you, but I asked for windows 10.

Comment: You’re welcome. I don’t have immediate access to a Windows 10 system — have you tried these to see whether they (also) work on Windows 10?

Comment: I will when I’m at my pc, I’ll be back and tell you how it went.

Comment: It seems to have worked, thx.

Comment: @Aresiel - This answer works for Windows 10.